# Combo Box Internal Link Selector HTML

Tags: html, hyperlink, combobox, selector, internal

I'm trying to include a combo box on my websites homepage, that will jump to specific internal links when the correct value is selected. I have this test code so far but I haven't managed to strike any luck! Could anyone let me know where I am going wrong? Many thanks in advance!

```html
<body>
    <select>
      <option><a href="#Nature">Nature</a></option>
      <option><a href="#Motion">Motion</a></option>
      <option><a href="#Potraiture">Portraiture</a></option>
      <option><a href="#Stilllife">Still Life</a></option>
    </select>

    <a name="Nature"><p>This is the Nature section</p></a>
    <a name="Motion"><p>This is the Motion section</p></a>
    <a name="Portraiture"><p>This is the Portraiture section</p></a>
    <a name="Stilllife"><p>This is the Still Life section</p></a>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close-ish, but unfortunately anchor (`<a>`) tags don't work inside `<select>` `<option>` tags. To get around this, we can use a javascript function on an option value, as below:

```
<select onchange="document.getElementById(this.value).scrollIntoView();">
      <option value="Nature">Nature</option>
      <option value="Motion">Motion</option>
      <option value="Potraiture">Portraiture</option>
      <option value="Stilllife">Still Life</option>
</select>

<div id="Nature"><p>This is the Nature section</p></div>
<div id="Motion"><p>This is the Motion section</p></div>
<div id="Portraiture"><p>This is the Portraiture section</p></div>
<div id="Stilllife"><p>This is the Still Life section</p></div>
```

Note I've also changed the `<a>` tags to `<div>`s. This seemed more semantically and syntactically correct to me, obviously if I'm incorrect feel free to revert that change.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the javascript code to handle the changes in the selection, plus the action to take (go to another url).

```
var selectedOption = $("#DropDownList1 option:selected").text();

$("#DropDownList1").change(function(e) {
      url: "yoursite.com/default.aspx?#" + selectedOption;
      window.location = url;
});
```